# Point intersection of $y=2^x$ and $y=1/x$

Tags: calculus

Im trying find the point intersection of the functions.

$$y=2^x$$
$$y=1/x$$

I know that to solve this, the equations are equated.

$$2^x=1/x$$
$$2^x*x=1$$

but, how solve this??

Comment: [this may be relevant to you](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: You should use $\cdot$ or no symbol for multiplication in this context, as $*$ looks like convolution

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}x2^x&=1\\xe^{x\ln(2)}&=1\\x\ln(2)e^{x\ln(2)}&=\ln(2)\\x\ln(2)&=W(\ln(2))\\x&=\frac{W(\ln(2))}{\ln(2)}\end{align}
See [Lambert $W$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), defined by $y = xe^x \iff x=W(y)$.

Comment: and how can I graph this point? because geogebra solve $p=(0.64,1.56)$

Comment: @Isham Oh absolutely, thanks!

Comment: +1 no problem @ArnaudMortier

Comment: @MathYobani Geogebra computes an approximation, and this is all you can hope for I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use Lambert function, consider that you are looking for the zero of function
$$f(x)=2^x\,x-1$$ the derivatives of which being
$$f'(x)=2^x (x \log (2)+1) \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=2^x \log (2) (x \log (2)+2)$$ The first deivative cancels at
$$x_*=-\frac{1}{\log (2)}\implies f(x_*)=-1-\frac{1}{e \log (2)}\approx 0.255 \implies f''(x_*)=\frac{\log (2)}{e} >0$$ So, you have one root which $> x_*$.

By inspection, $f(0)=-1$ and $f(1)=1$. So, let us start Newton method using $x_0=\frac 12$ to get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.5000000000 \\
 1 & 0.6538027945 \\
 2 & 0.6412785001 \\
 3 & 0.6411857496 \\
 4 & 0.6411857445
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.

You can notice that we have, at the first iteration, an overshoot of the solution : this is normal (by Darboux-Fourier theorem) since
$$f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-1 <0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\log ^2(2)}{\sqrt{2}}+2 \sqrt{2} \log (2) >0$$

Answer (score 1):

The intersection point cannot be represented by elementary functions. In fact, it is x=W(ln(2))/ln(2). Here, W is the product log function.

Comment: There are not friends of mine or something like that. I thought this website was about math, not about being rude to people who are trying to get smarter. Do whatever you want.

Comment: I accepted the suggestion of posting my work together with the question, but you should not be so mad at me. I'm starting here now. This must not be good for your heart.